# Change of variables for the heat equation into moving coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}
$$

for $u=u(t,x)$.

Now, express the equation in moving coordinates $t$ and $\xi=x-ct$.

I see two possibilities:

(1) Consider $U=U(t,\xi)$ and compute $\frac{d}{dt}U(t,\xi)$ and $\frac{d^2}{d\xi^2}U(t,\xi)$ which gives me the equation
$$
U_t=cU_{\xi}+U_{\xi\xi}.
$$

(2) Consider
$u=u(t,\xi+ct)$ (since this equals $u(t,x)$) and put it into the equation, what gives me

$$
u_t=-cu_{\xi}+u_{\xi\xi}.
$$

So I nearly get the same.

Which is the possibility that is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the chain rule:

$$u_t(t,x)=\dfrac{du(t,\xi)}{d t}=\dfrac{\partial u(t,\xi)}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial u(t,\xi)}{\partial \xi}\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial t}=u_t(t,\xi)-cu_{\xi}(t,\xi)$$

$$u_x(t,x)=\dfrac{du(t,\xi)}{d x}=\dfrac{\partial u(t,\xi)}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u(t,\xi)}{\partial \xi}\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}=u_{\xi}(t,\xi)$$

$$u_{xx}(t,x)=\dfrac{du_{\xi}(t,\xi)}{d x}=\dfrac{\partial u_{\xi}(t,\xi)}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u_{\xi}(t,\xi)}{\partial \xi}\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}=u_{\xi\xi}(t,\xi)$$
For the second spatial derivative you have to use the chain rule twice.

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Your notation is a little funky. Both $u_t$ and $\frac{\partial u(t, \xi)}{\partial t}$ are referring to partial derivatives, but you actually want a total derivative, which would be written as $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}$. It makes a difference here, when the partial derivative is computed with respect to only the first argument of $u$, whereas the total derivative accounts for the dependency of $\xi$ on $t$.

Comment: Okay, if you have a look at my edit, thats nearly what I did, but I thought I have to consider $u(t,\xi+ct)$ since this equals $u(t,x)$. But as I can see from your answer, I simply have to consider $u(t,\xi)$.

Comment: @Michael Lee: Thank you for you comment. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @MichaelLee I cannot see your argument. I would like to have $u_t$ which is notation for partial derivative. So why do you think about total derivative? Sorry, I did not get that.

Comment: @MrYouMath I can follow your computation but not why, for example, you write $u_t(t,x)=\frac{du(t,\xi)}{dt}$.

Comment: @MrYouMath Never mind, I was reading you incorrectly. Sorry about that.

Comment: You need to finde the total variation of u with respect to t after the substitution. Initially the partial derivative was enough, but after substitution your t, was also involved in the second coordinate.

Comment: But I am interested only in partial derivatives, sorry for writing $d/dt$ in my post instead of $\partial/\partial t$, say.

Comment: OKAY; got what you mean, sorry :D

Comment: Another way to do it is to also introduce a new time-coordinate $t' = t$ then use the chain rule to compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$.